# Exponential backoff algorithm

Tags: networking

When a collision occurs, a Jamming signal is sent to prevent further data being sent. Later, after some k μs, the frame is resent. If there is a collision during that time also, then resend it after some k1 μs. If there is a collision even during that time,  resend it after k2 μs.

I searched the internet and got the below link that conveys that the random value lies between 0 and ((2 to the power of n) − 1), where 'n' is the count of the failed attempt.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff

But,I am interested in the value '51.2 μs'.
The above link conveys '51.2 μs' as an example value. But, what should be optimal value to start with ? Any ideas ?

Thx in advans,
Karthik Balaguru

Comment: To whoever marked this as smells-like-homework, homework questions ARE permitted (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow), but the answer should be treated differently, perhaps by giving all the pieces to the puzzle, but not the actual answer. See also here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34503/should-the-possible-homework-tag-be-discouraged

Answer (score 1):

The value of 51.2 μs is the time taken to transmit a frame of the minimum allowed size (64 bytes) on a 10baseT (10 Mbps) ethernet network (64 bytes = 512 bits = 51.2μs @ 10 Mbps).

The jamming signal is transmitted for this time to ensure all stations on the segment detect the collision.

Comment: And therefore that time is specified by whatever link layer you are using.  There is no per-se 'optimal' value, it is what works for the particular physical medium.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the optimal value for *k1*?  It should be different for each machine.

You want the resends to happen as quickly as possible, without another collision.  If each machine's *k1* is different, then machine1's retransmission won't interfere with machine2's.

Specifically, the optimal *k1* will be larger than the time it takes to send a single packet of <strike>maximum</strike> *minimum* size for whatever link layer technology is being used.

Comment: Thx for the response, but the query is not about the k1.
The link conveys the below info - "The figure 51.2μs has been given here as an example. However, 51.2μs could be replaced by any positive value, in practice." 

I am looking for the optimal value instead of 51.2μs. Any ideas ?

Comment: in that example, 51.2μs *is* the example's *k1*.

Comment: so... what link tech are we talking about, exactly?  10base5? 10baseT? ... _*gasp*_ please tell me it's not 10base2...